# I have an image fade out on load but I only want it to happen once

Tags: javascript, html

```js
< script >
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById('me').classList.add('fade');
  }, 1700); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
  <div class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="now.html">What I'm Doing Now</a></li>
          <li><a href="lessons.html">Lessons I've Learned</a></li>
          <li><a href="xoxo.html">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="dating.html">Dating/Relationships</a></li>
          <li><a href="therapy.html">Therapy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a background image fade out when the page first loads. But when visitors click on the links and go to another page and come back to index.html, I don't want the image to be visible again. I just want visitors to see it once  when they first visit the index.html page. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that is happening is because each time your page loads, it counts as a new load. You are not saving any data or state when the page loads, so it doesn't know that the page has been loaded when you try the second time.

You can try two things using javascript.

1. Save a cookie and then check if the cookie exists before loading the image.
2. Save some value to local storage and then check if the value is set before loading the image.